# Is $AA^\ast \preceq B^\ast B$ implies $\bar{\sigma}(A)\le \underline{\sigma}(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Given two matrices $A$ and $B$, the question is whether $AA^\ast \preceq B^\ast B$ implies any relation between the singular values of the matrices.

For example,
$$\bar{\sigma}(A)\le \underline{\sigma}(B),$$
where $\bar{\sigma}(\cdot)$ and $\underline{\sigma}(\cdot)$ are the maximal and minimal singular values of a matrix, respectively.

Comment: You should put the entire question in the body. In particular, you should say what $A,B,\underline{\sigma},\bar\sigma$ are.

Comment: 1) Especially $\bar \sigma$ and $\underline \sigma$. I didn't see and can't find this notation. 2) Any reason why matrix multiplications are in a different order? Why not $A^\ast A \preceq B^\ast B$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, I clarified the notation.

Comment: Try $A=\begin{bmatrix}3&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}4&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Hmmm?  How did you get that?   Maybe I misunderstand your question.  What is the operator $(\_)^*$?  Is it the usual Hermitian conjugate?  If that is so, you should have $A^*=A$ and $B^*=B$.

Comment: @Batominovski Oops, thanks! Are you familiar with any other relation between the SV of A and B under the above condition.

Comment: @Morad  I don't know any, and I don't expect any, unless there are more restrictions on $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

$AA^*\leq B^*B$  implies

$\big(AA^*\big)^\frac{1}{2}\leq \big(B^*B\big)^\frac{1}{2}$
where the LHS has the same singular values as $A$ and the RHS has the same singular values as $B$.
Proof:  [If $0 \le A \le B$ then $\sqrt{A} \le \sqrt{B}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3516718/if-0-le-a-le-b-then-sqrta-le-sqrtb)

with singular values in the usual ordering $\sigma_1\geq \sigma_2\geq ...\geq \sigma_n$
using the left singular vectors of $A$
$U^{(k)} := \mathbf u_1\mathbf u_1^*+\mathbf u_2\mathbf u_2^* + ... + \mathbf u_k\mathbf u_k^*$

thus
$\sum_{j=1}^k \sigma_j^{(A)}=\text{trace}\Big(U\big(AA^*\big)^\frac{1}{2}\Big)\leq \text{trace}\Big(U\big(BB^*\big)^\frac{1}{2}\Big)\leq \sum_{j=1}^k \sigma_j^{(B)}$

where the second inequality follows from von Neuman Trace Inequality and the first inequality comes from $\big(AA^*\big)^\frac{1}{2}\leq \big(BB^*\big)^\frac{1}{2}$ i.e.

$\text{trace}\Big(U\big(AA^*\big)^\frac{1}{2}\Big) = \mathbf u_1^*\big(AA^*\big)^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf u_1+\mathbf u_2^*\big(AA^*\big)^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf u_2 + ... + \mathbf u_k^*\big(AA^*\big)^\frac{1}{2}\mathbf u_k^*$

The conclusion is that
$\Sigma^{(A)}\preceq_w \Sigma^{(B)}$
where $\preceq_w$ denotes weak majorization.