# If $A^2\succeq B^2$ then $A\succeq B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n×n$ symmetric matrices such that $A,B\succeq0$ ($A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite) and $A^2\succeq B^2$. Is the following inequality true? $$A\succeq B$$ In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510895/is-it-true-that-a2-succ-b2-implies-that-a-succ-b-but-not-the-converse), it's shown that (I couldn't understand the proof) if we replace "semidefinite" with "definite" in the above proposition, the inequality is true but I don't know whether it holds in this case.

Comment: The link you provide actually proves what you ask right ? What part of the proof don't you get ?

Comment: @P.Quinton It proves if $A,B\succ 0$ and $A^2\succ B^2$ then $A\succ B$. I'm asking about the same proposition with $\succ$ replaced by $\succeq$. In the proof, it's assumed that $A^{-1}$ exists but a positive semidefinite matrix can be singular.

Comment: Well the third paragraph (the limiting argument) is about if $0\preceq B^2 \preceq A^2$ then $0\preceq B \preceq A$ when $0\preceq A,B$.

Comment: if you want to do this directly without appealing to limits, consider: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3516718/if-0-le-a-le-b-then-sqrta-le-sqrtb/

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks, I think it solves the problem. It would be great if you post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @P.Quinton You're right, I didn't pay attention. By the way, I don't know how to make it rigorous. It holds for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ but we need some continuity condition to let $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @S.H.W. With the definition of "positive semidefinite", you can show that the limit of a sequence of positive semidefinite matrices is positive semidefinite.

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's really interesting. Would you provide a reference?

Comment: @S.H.W I could type a proof as an answer, but I don't have a reference offhand

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's even better :). I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the "limiting argument" in the linked answer, it suffices to show that if $(A + tI) \succeq B$ for all $t > 0$, then $A \succeq B$.

Recall that a symmetric real matrix $M$ is positive semidefinite if for all vectors $x \in \Bbb R^n$, $x^TMx \geq 0$. Let $t_k = 1/k$. We note that for each $k$, $(A + t_k I) - B$ is positive semidefinite, so that $x^T[(A + t_k I) - B]x \geq 0$. Now, we have
$$
x^T(A - B)x = \lim_{k \to \infty}x^T[(A + t_k I) - B]x.
$$
The limit of a sequence of non-negative numbers is necessarily non-negative. Thus, $x^T(A - B)x \geq 0$. Since this holds for all vectors $x$, we conclude that $A - B \succeq 0$, which is to say that $A \succeq B$ as was desired.

Comment: I think you meant "positive semidefinite" by "positive definite".

Comment: @S.H.W That's right, thanks